# Django increasing value in database on update

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

i have table for inventory where is Qty column, i will like to add Qty using form to sum new value with already existed in database

my class based view in views.py looks like :

```
class ItemUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
model = Stock
template_name = 'users/item_update_form.html'
fields = ['qty']
```

right now im getting this output :

screenshot from page view

[image: screenshot from page view]

i will like to have empty Qty Field to type new value and after pressing Add increase value already existing in database with this new value

Comment: then use another `Form` with a different field, not `qty`. When saving the form, change the value of  `qty` on the model using an `F` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the field that is stored at the database level for quantity in the expression to save:

```
from django.db.models import F

class ItemUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Stock
    template_name = 'users/item_update_form.html'
    fields = ['qty']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.qty += F('qty')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Willem , thx, thats works strait , one more question. is any chance to get Qty empty field in front end form , right now is always showing what is in database , then need to delete the value and then type new, (increasing works great btw)